# Bootstrap 4 different popover & tooltip styles for each elements

Tags: html, css, tooltip, popover, using

I want give different styles to tooltip and popover elements for each sections on Bootstrap 4 For example:

A color and other css options for this element:

```
<div class="first-type">
    <div data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" title="About Us" data-placement="left">
        <a href="#about" class="item-class"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And another css options for this element:

```
<div class="second-type">
    <div data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" title="Services" data-placement="left">
        <a href="#services" class="item-class"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Bootstrap 3x adding the popover codes into the element. And i can give styles easily with element's classes. But Bootstrap 4 adding the popover codes to body. How i can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Via js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
        trigger: 'click',
        template: '<div class="popover awesome-popover-class"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="popover-inner"><h3 class="popover-title"></h3><div class="popover-content"><p></p></div></div></div>'
    });  
});
```

Comment: Bootstrap 4 adding the popover html codes to body> . So that css is not working.

Comment: You can use custom template.